# Typeof considers class instead of variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, typeof

There is a string variable which has same name as of a class. The Console.WriteLine" displays the string content when I display, but points to the class when I try typeof(). Why?

```
class Fun { }
class MyFun
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string Fun = "hello, world";
        string s = Fun;
        Type t = typeof(Fun);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: because `typeof` expects type as parameter

Comment: That is how it is defined. You can use GetType on variable

Comment: More "fun" and relevance: `class Fun { public static int Length => 42; }
  class MyFun
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      string Fun = "hello, world";

      var greatFun = Fun.Length;
    }
  }` In this case, `Fun.Length` could be either the instance property of the local variable, or the `static` property of the type. The first one is assumed. To get the second one, qualify `Fun` with a namespace (if necessary, use `global::` namespace alias). _This is one reason to not name local variables with a capital initial letter._

Answer (score 2):

Since `Fun` is a *local variable*, not a *type name* (e.g. `string`), the right syntax is

```
 Type t = Fun.GetType();
```

Or (if you want `typeof`):

```
 Type t = typeof(string);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx for details

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't `typeof` a variable, just a type. Hence, the class is picked.

For variables, you have access to `object.GetType()`:

```
Type t = Fun?.GetType();
```